# Github Action running "terraform plan" failing with a 404

Tags: terraform, github-actions

I am running the following Github action that should post the output from `terraform plan`to the PR in Github but it's giving me a 404. I have pretty much copied the [action from Terraform](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hashicorp/learn-terraform-github-actions/main/.github/workflows/terraform.yml)

The only thing I can see that is suspect is the URL that's generating the 404 looks like it's missing a value - it says
"https://api.github.com/repos/orgname/reponame/issues//comments" but I think it probably should be
"https://api.github.com/repos/orgname/reponame/issues/SOMETHING/comments":

```
      - name: Run Terraform Plan
        id: plan
        run: |
          cd operations/app/terraform/vars/staging
          terraform plan -no-color -input=false
        continue-on-error: true

      - uses: actions/github-script@v6
        env:
          PLAN: "terraform\n${{ steps.plan.outputs.stdout }}"
        with:
          github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          script: |
            const output = `#### Terraform Format and Style  \`${{ steps.fmt.outcome }}\`
            #### Terraform Initialization ⚙️\`${{ steps.init.outcome }}\`
            #### Terraform Validation \`${{ steps.validate.outcome }}\`
            #### Terraform Plan \`${{ steps.plan.outcome }}\`

            <details><summary>Show Plan</summary>

            \`\`\`\n
            ${process.env.PLAN}
            \`\`\`

            </details>

            *Pusher: @${{ github.actor }}, Action: \`${{ github.event_name }}\`*`;

            github.rest.issues.createComment({
              issue_number: context.issue.number,
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              body: output
            })
```

I get the following:

```
  
  Plan: 0 to add, 1 to change, 0 to destroy.
  
  ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
  
  Note: You didn't use the -out option to save this plan, so Terraform can't
  guarantee to take exactly these actions if you run "terraform apply" now.
  

RequestError [HttpError]: Not Found
    at /home/runner/work/_actions/actions/github-script/v6/dist/index.js:4469:21
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) ***
  status: 404,
  response: ***
    url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/myorg/myrepo/issues//comments',
Error: Unhandled error: HttpError: Not Found
    status: 404,
    headers: ***
<snip headers>
    data: ***
      message: 'Not Found',
      documentation_url: 'https://docs.github.com/rest'
    ***
  ***,
  request: ***
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/orgname/reponame/issues//comments',
    headers: ***
      accept: 'application/vnd.github.-preview+json',
      'user-agent': 'actions/github-script octokit-core.js/3.5.1 Node.js/16.13.0 (linux; x64)',
      authorization: 'token [REDACTED]',
      'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    ***,
```

Comment: One thing I realized is that it's running even when no PR is being done so that would make it fail. Added a conditional so it only runs on a PR and trying again

Comment: I think that may help. I realized after I posted my answer that maybe the workflow is being triggered by an event that's not `pull_request`, which would potentially cause `context.issue.number` to be empty, resulting in the 404 you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `await` in front of the function call in your action.

```
await github.rest.issues.createComment({
  issue_number: context.issue.number,
  owner: context.repo.owner,
  repo: context.repo.repo,
  body: output
})
```

Comment: Same result (no change in output)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was this was running on both `push` and `pull_request` - but on a `push` there is no PR for it to add the comment to so that portion failed. Adding a conditional for the github-script got it working as expected

```
  - uses: actions/github-script@v6
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
    env:
```